# Microsoft Excel VBA code range based on cell contents

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code, and I have a problem with a range.

In my excel sheet, I want the range to be based on the contents of cell C2.

Here is the VBA code,

```
Sub Repeat()
'
' Repeat Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:A3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:A19").Select
    Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

However, instead of A19 I would ideally like to use the AX with X being the value in cell C2, if cell C2 contains 24 I would like it to say A24 instead of A19 any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like your question is not complete. As if you are manually doing something that can be easily automated. Why are you typing a range to autofill? Can't this be done automatically? Is "24" the last row or is there something else that makes "24" *the* number?

Comment: What type of data do you have in `A1:A3`?

Comment: @Andreas I would ideally like the range to be the first X cells in A which have data in them. This will change, is there any easy fix?

Comment: Yes that is an easy fix. But what is X cells? You need to be more specific on what makes X. Do you mean to the last filled row in column A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Range("A1:A" & Range("C2").value)
```

But you should qualify with the sheet name as well.

For example:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1:A3").AutoFill Destination:= .Range("A1:A" & .Range("C2").value)    , Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```